Preventing Excel Ribbon CustomUI IRibbonUI variable from 'losing state'
We have a custom UI with two added ribbons in our Workspace Environment. This CustomUI has an OnLoad event that loads the Ribbon's pointer variable into memory for access later. Unfortunately, there is no clear mechanism to get this state variable back if the code has an abrupt stop and loses its state. The only way that seems apparent is to restart Excel. I need a way to get the IRibbonUI variable back into memory if it is lost.

While I was searching through the internet, I came to a reference to an article by Ron de Bruin, unfortunately for the Windows Excel programming world he has chosen to remove his Windows material from the Internet. I was able to dig through the internet archive and I found his solution which I found quite elegant, and I implemented immediately. Since this CustomUI is tied to an add-in; I don't have problems storing information on a sheet since it is hidden and unused, but I also came across another option for storing in the variable in the .Net domain. I'll share both
Ron de Bruin's Solution based on an Excel MVP RoyA here.
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias _ 
        "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef destination As Any, ByRef source As Any, ByVal length As Long)

#If VBA7 Then
Public Function GetRibbon(ByVal lRibbonPointer As LongPtr) As Object
#Else
Public Function GetRibbon(ByVal lRibbonPointer As Long) As Object
#End If
        Dim objRibbon As Object
        CopyMemory objRibbon, lRibbonPointer, LenB(lRibbonPointer)
        Set GetRibbon = objRibbon
        Set objRibbon = Nothing
End Function

Public Sub GetVisibleRibbon(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef visible)
    If MyTag = "show" Then
        visible = True
    Else
        If control.Tag Like MyTag Then
            visible = True
        Else
            visible = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public Function RefreshRibbon(Tag As String) As IRibbonUI
    MyTag = Tag
    If MyRibbonUI Is Nothing Then
        Set MyRibbonUI = GetRibbon(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A30").Value)
        MyRibbonUI.Invalidate
        MsgBox "The Ribbon handle was lost, Hopefully this is sorted now by the GetRibbon Function?. You can remove this msgbox, I only use it for testing"
    Else
        MyRibbonUI.Invalidate
    End If
    Set RefreshRibbon = MyRibbonUI
End Function

Public Sub OnRibbonLoad(ribbonUI As IRibbonUI)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set MyRibbonUI = ribbonUI
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A30").Value = ObjPtr(ribbonUI)
End Sub

I've modified Ron's solution turning RefreshRibbon into a function instead of a Sub and therefore, it can be used as the variable in all the locations where that variable is used within the code.
Then I came across this Stack Overflow question posed by another user that did not like the solution that used a cell storage of an object pointer, so I thought I would link this post here
-CJ
